# How to mock some beans but not others in MockMVC?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, mocking, mockito

I'm trying to write a unit test for a controller. Some of the dependencies (such as a service class) I'm mocking with `@MockBean`. But there are other dependencies I want to just have spring create the beans as usual. Is this possible?

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(JwtAuthenticationController.class)
public class JwtControllerTests {

    @MockBean
    private JwtUserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;

    @MockBean
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @ ? ? ?
    private JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil

    public void auth_Success() throws Exception {
        when(
            jwtUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(anyString())
        ).thenReturn(adminUserDetails);

        RequestBuilder request = MockMvcRequestBuilders
            .post("/api/v1/authenticate")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content(authBody);
    }
}
```

Controller code:

```
public class JwtAuthenticationController {
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;
    @Autowired
    private JwtUserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have @WebMvcTest.

> Annotation that can be used for a Spring MVC test that focuses
> **only** on Spring MVC components.

You need to use @SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class) and configure your MockMvc.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = DemoApplication.class)
public class JwtControllerTests {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;


    @MockBean
    private JwtUserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;

    @MockBean
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;


    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new JwtAuthenticationController(authenticationManager,jwtUserDetailsService,jwtTokenUtil))
                .addInterceptors(interceptor)
                .setControllerAdvice(exceptionTranslator)
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void auth_Success() throws Exception {
        when(
                jwtUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(anyString())
        ).thenReturn(adminUserDetails);

        RequestBuilder request = MockMvcRequestBuilders
                .post("/api/v1/authenticate")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(authBody);

         mockMvc.perform(request).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

Change your `JwtAuthenticationController` to accept dependencies by the constructor.

Comment: Same error still Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type JwtTokenUtil' available:

Comment: I updated my answer. I didn't see @WebMvcTest before.

Comment: Do you know how this approach compares to keeping @WebMvcTest but then adding @Import({JwtTokenUtil.class) which seems to make the error go away.

Comment: It's the same; the only difference is that using @Import, you include explicit the dependencies, the other way you have access to all spring context.

Comment: In your approach if I don't need explicit reference to jwkTokenUtil, but the controller needs it, do I still have to autowire it in the test class?

Comment: Yes, because you are creating by hand the resource, using  new JwtAuthenticationController(authenticationManager,jwtUserDetailsService,jwtTokenUtil). The first two dependencies are @MockBean and only JwtTokenUtil is a real bean.

Comment: no but I don't want to create JwtAuthenticationController by hand, I want the MockMvcRequestBuilders to make the http request. In that case can I skip the autowire? I updated my question to show the request builder.

Comment: You can use MockMvcRequestBuilders in any approach. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can @SpyBean

```
@SpyBean
private JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil
```